# Jquery datepicker - do not preselect dates

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker, mindate

I have two jquery datepickers, one for selecting arrival date, the other for departure. The problem is I cannot seem to find out how NOT to have preselected dates. As soon as the datepicker is inited and I request the getDate(), it returns me a date. Without any user interaction.

The second problem is that once I select a date in the "arrival datepicker", it automatically sets the minDate for the "departure datepicker". That's nice, the problem is that it automatically selects this date, too. I do not want it to select the date, I just want it to disable all the days till the minDate day.

How to avoid this? (or just simply deselect the selected date) Thanks in advance!

The code is:

```
var a = $("#arrival_date_datepicker");
var d = $("#departure_date_datepicker");

a.datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date){
        d.datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
        d.datepicker("option", "defaultDate", null);
    },
    minDate: 0
});

d.datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date){

    },
    minDate: 0
});
```

Comment: Ops, could clear the date with a.datepicker("setDate", null); However still cannot clear the date from the departure one after setting its minDate.

Comment: I can't see the second problem occurring in your code. It seems to be working fine unless. I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/hzUZB/1/). Please check and confirm what the problem is...

Comment: My apologies, I didn't make myself clear. The second problem is that it "selects visually" the date in the 2nd datepicker (it gets the active state), despite the fact that it is not selected. This seems to be rather confusing.

Comment: The datepicker selects the current date by default. Is that what you are talking about? Think that is the default behaviour...

Comment: I guess so but not quite sure what you mean under "current date". Let's assume today's red, selected date (by user) is blue. Nothing else matters. Now if I select 25 July, it gets the blue active state because it is selected. In the second datepicker 26 July will get blue too - as it was selected but it is actually not. I cannot seem to remove the 'highlight' from it.

Comment: I have just realized - this bug does not occur in your example. Seems like the datepickers must be either visible or 'attached' to a div. Here is a modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/uwHyp/ As you can see, if you select a date in the first calendar, the second calendar gets a highlighted date as well, despite the fact that it is not selected.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I see what you are talking about. So you are modifying your `div` or still looking to fix your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... I changed the div to input, however I would prefer the div-way. If you have any idea how to fix it without ruining other stuff, I would appreciate it!